# How to send js array in Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, spring-mvc

I have created a JS array like this `var detailsArr = new Array();` and pushing some data into this array.

Now i push this array via Ajax to my Spring Controller like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit",
            data: ({detailsArr : detailsArr }),
            success: function(html){
              alert( "Submitted");
                }
          });
```

At the Spring Controller side ,  i receive this array through the `@RequestBody` annotation. The Spring Controller method signature looks like this

```
public String submit(@RequestBody String body)
```

But the array when received at the Spring Controller side is basically a String of this format

```
detailsArr[]=add&detailsArr[]=test1&detailsArr[]=test2&detailsArr[]=test3
```

I have to manually split this String to get the values, this is a cumbersome process. Is there any way in which I can get the array as it is , so that I just have to iterate over it to get the values.

Comment: Please add the method signature from your spring controller (with annotations) and a dump of `detailsArr` (`console.log` it or something like that)

Comment: The signature of my Spring controller looks like this 
`public String submit(@RequestBody String body)`   and the dump of the detailsArr is like this
`detailsArr[]=add&detailsArr[]=test1&detailsArr[]=test2&detailsArr[]=test3`

Comment: after you read request body, u should get a string formatted in json, and then u should write or use a JsonUtil and convert your json string to class(array or what you want, what your format)

Comment: but the String format that I am getting does not seem to be formatted in JSON, I am not sure about this... but a hunch....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should pass your array to server in json format. And convert it by using Json to object converter. you can use `Gson`.

client side:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submit",
            data:JSON.stringify(detailsArr),
            success: function(html){
              alert( "Submitted");
                }
          });
```

server side :

```
public String submit(@RequestBody String body){
//convert body to array using JSONLib, FlexJSON or Gson
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When passing it to your controller, pass it like this:

```
data:JSON.stringify(detailsArr);
```

At your controller, you can then decode the JSON received.