# Send list with ajax to my Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring

I'm having a problem with Spring MVC and Ajax. I'm trying to send a javascript list to my Spring Controller, but I can't. I've to do a search and I need to send a list with some parameters.

Comment: May be helpful if you provide a short example of your javascript, the ajax call and how do you know its not working? Are you getting a javascript error or an error on the server side or both?

Comment: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert to the list to json if you sending via ajax, this [From the spring blog itself](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) :

```
$("#account").submit(function() {
    var account = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.postJSON("account", account, function(data) {
        $("#assignedId").val(data.id);
        showPopup();
    });
    return false;
});


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> create(@RequestBody Account account, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> failures = validator.validate(account);
    if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return validationMessages(failures);
    } else {
        accounts.put(account.assignId(), account);
        return Collections.singletonMap("id", account.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your list to JSON String , before using it as an AJAX parameter

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265717/how-to-send-js-array-in-ajax) in SO might help

jquery ajax on client side

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit",
        data:JSON.stringify(detailsArr),
        success: function(html){
          alert( "Submitted");
            }
      });
```

and on server side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String yourMethod(@RequestBody String body){
//convert body to array using JSONLib, FlexJSON or Gson
}
```